# HAXM x86 android emulation never finish loading

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I create virtual android device with x86 cpu:

[image]

it is starting:

[image]

but never finish loading. CPU is actively consumed, "ANDROID" title is animating, but loading never finishes. Non-x86 cpus load much faster, but still very slow...

I have

- HAXM installed (before installing it, emulator didn't start with x86 cpu), i used "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\silent_install.bat"
- Tried both memory > 700M and < 700M, nothing changes

[image: my cpu]

Answer (score 0):

what actual system are you on?
Have you tried just downloading HAXM from Intel and installing from that?
-   https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
and if still issues - list what CPU you have.

Comment: Installed software from the link you gave, it doesn't help. Also add screenshot with my CPU info.